# What's wrong in this code? It keep writing the same value

Tags: python, mysql, insert

it inserts same value every time.

```
import re
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","123","tc" )
cursor = db.cursor()
for x in range(1,2):
        file = '/tmp/tc/'
        file +=`x`
        file +=".txt"
        f = open(file, 'r')
        print x
        listTC = re.findall(r'[1-9]{1}[0-9]{10}', f.read())
        for item in listTC:
                print item
                sql = "INSERT INTO TCNO (tcno) VALUES(%s);"
                cursor.execute(sql % (item))
```

OUTPUT in MYSQL SERVER:

```
| 94006 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94007 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94008 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94009 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94010 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94011 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94012 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94013 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94014 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94015 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94016 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94017 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94018 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94019 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94020 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94021 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94022 | 2147483647 | NULL |
| 94023 | 2147483647 | NULL |
+-------+------------+------+
94023 rows in set (0.11 sec)
```

However, in the console when I am printing the item:

```
69619195972
32386362700
70930135288
20371250224
25069684954
32414357302
55660438298
12352807312
18566819172
53425735712
19622042220
34060374108
49126586180
13184124554
18772590346
38074262024
37765310686
15491265104
16139670014
16799684314
22231833554
22231833554
21389016246
44923993452
50902266134
30742937128
34071994144
35011994174
```

Comment: What's being printed for `x` and `item`?

Comment: Would be useful [critical] to know the contents of `f`.

Comment: x is there is 50 file name. Therefore it will open files at that range and item is numbers in the files. There is no problem with item. It print unique numbers. However, when I look up the databases. There is one number and thosands of rows

Comment: nothing important it gets the numbers in the file and puting to the listTC.Also, I checking the number with printing the item. It always unique.

Comment: And your `print sql % (item)` statements all are correct?

Comment: What version of python? if it's 2.6 or better.  format() might be a better option than %()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2147483647` is `0x7fffffff`, so probably you hit max signed int value.

Take a look on data type on the field at database designers, and probably use Big Integer or something bigger one.

ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html#id603844

Answer (score 0):

It's because of range(1,2):

```
for x in range(1,2):
...   print x
...
1
for x in range(0,2):
...   print x
...
0
1
```